# C# Method Name Expected - Multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've  created this program in C# but I'm getting a 'Method Name Expected' error. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberofThreads2; i++)     
{   
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart (Start(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
    thread1.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating your thread delegate wrong.  Try:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Start(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 4):

`ThreadStart` is a delegate with the signature `void ThreadStart()`.  This isn't the same as calling `Start(...)`, which actually runs `Start` immediately, rather than passing a delegate to do so in the new thread.  You're probably looking for `Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Start(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));`, which creates a lambda equiavlent to the following method, which can be converted to a `ThreadStart`:

```
void myLambda()
{
    Start(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadStart` is expecting the name of a method since ThreadStart is a delegate and its purpose is to encapsulate a method.

Like here

```
public void foo () { }

ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(()=> Start(1,2,3,4,5)).Start();
```